# Accessible controls for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, accessibility

In my last job we ended up rewriting the complete ASP.NET stack (forms, controls, validation, postback handling, ajax library etc...) - the reason I was given was that the ASP.NET controls were not accessible enough, not were any of the third party controls that were assessed for the project.

Can anyone point me to good accessible ASP.NET controls that do ajax as well?

Failing that, how would you approach creating accessible, ajax enabled controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the 'App_Browsers' feature in .NET.

It gives you the opportunity to hook into the rendering engine for each control.  The original intention for this was to be able to alter the HTML output of controls depending on the user's browser - but you can also do it for all browsers.

You could also take a look at [these control adapters](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/), which make the normal ASP.NET controls 'CSS Friendly'.